# Problem with a function to filter results defined in a computed property on vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm studying vue.js and I create a little project: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-gould-hs7k5?file=/src/components/Modal.vue
. I've created two components: Home and Modal. When I click on a button defined in the Home I opened a modal. In this component I used two dependencies: axios and infinite scroll. I create a function "loadMore" that I invoke on mounted property. This function load elements, that I stored in "photos" variable, from a GET call. After this I wanted to implementes a search filter bar. I created an input tag with a v-model "searchString". I defined this property in the data and I created a function "filteredResources" that filters the results.

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "Modal",
  data() {
    return {
      photos: [],
      results: [],
      busy: false,
      limit: 10,
      searchString: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    loadMore() {
      this.busy = true;
      axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")
        .then(res => {
          const append = res.data.slice(
            this.photos.length,
            this.photos.length + this.limit
          );
          this.photos = this.photos.concat(append);
          this.busy = false;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
          this.busy = false;
        });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadMore();
  },
  computed: {
    filteredResources: () => {
      if (!this.searchString) return this.photos;
      let regex = new RegExp(this.searchString, "i");
      return this.photos.filter(photo => regex.test(photo.title));
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This is the template:

```
 <section class="modal-body">
        <slot name="body">
          <input type="text" v-model="searchString" placeholder="Enter your search terms">
          <ul>
            <div
              v-infinite-scroll="loadMore"
              infinite-scroll-disabled="busy"
              infinite-scroll-distance="limit"
              class="productsContainer">
              <li v-for="photo in photos" :key="photo.id">
                <img :src="photo.url" height="200">
                <p class="titleDescription">Title: {{photo.title}}</p>
              </li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </slot>
</section>
```

If in the v-for directive I tried to put filteredResources instead of photos, for doing a search, I get an error:
"[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchString' of undefined"

But if I try to debug when filteredResources is invoked the 'searchString' variable is defined like an empty string.

Comment: You need to switch the arrow function to a regular function. `filteredResources: () => {` to `filteredResources() {`. Otherwise you'll get the wrong `this` value.

Comment: thank you. It works. But I don't understand. The this value with arrow function was related to what?

Comment: With an arrow function the `this` value comes from the surrounding scope, i.e. the surrounding function. In your case there is no surrounding function, so `this` is `undefined`. Also, unrelated to your previous error but using a `RegExp` like that is going to cause you problems with special characters. e.g. Searching for `[` or `(` will result in errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 computed: {
    filteredResources: (){
      if (!this.searchString || this.searchString == '') return this.photos;
      let regex = new RegExp(this.searchString, "i");
      return this.photos.filter(photo => regex.test(photo.title));
    }
  }
```